# Three monitors in two graphics card in separate xorg screens Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, xorg.conf

I checked every article in askubuntu.com related setting 3 or 4 monitor with two graphics card. So there are some response regarding it and it says it is not possible at that time(around 2011 - 2014) because it has some bug. However I am interested in resent discoveries. Dose new X11 support putting monitors to separate screens? Do we have some success stories?